# call safari in iphone program

Tags: iphone

i am working on an application in which i needs to call safari when i click on a button.....
please tell me how to do this
should i create a new view for this ?
kindly help....
please also tell about importing messagebox and callmanager if possible.....
(not talking about sending msg or call from my app ...know that is not possible... i want to call inbuilt applications only) .
also wanto confirm that will my app close when i will call these inbuilt applications....

thanks....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://9016098909891"]];
```

You can use the above function to call from the iphone

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

USe this to open safari and so on.. hope yo got the idea what exactly to do....

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms://9016098909891"]];
```

uSe the above to send SMS from iphone

hAPPY cODING....

Comment: openURL takes a string parameter? 2nd example should also take a NSURL.

Comment: dats what i had noted after posting and hence edited it already...
Still thanks for showing me ma mistake..

Comment: @ranjeet: are you talking about sms?

Comment: i have added the sms part too..KINDLY CHECK. and as your question states that you want to open up the inbuilt stuffs in inbuilt and not in your application so YOUR APPLICATION WILL EXIT whenever you make any of the above calls

Answer (score 2):

If you call [openURL](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL:) with a general (for example not a youtube link) web page, then by default it will be opened through safari. However, your app will be terminated.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"]];
```

Sorry, can't help about the messagebox.

Comment: sorry i tried... but my reputation is less ....i will surely try it later...thanks again...