# Making a phone call from apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Here my app deals with phone call.After googling I found the code for calling a user from my app

```
NSURL *phoneNumber = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"tel:867-5309"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: phoneNumber];
```

This is my code.I don't know what is going on here, while making a call the device is using any protocols or else the code will initiate the normal dialing function of the device..

Whether itz compulsory to add Core Telephony Framework to my app?

Comment: Try removing the extra characters like -, space, symbols etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Where pPhoneNumber is your string phone number..

```
    NSString *deviceName = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;    
    if([deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
    {
        NSString *strDialedNumber = [pPhoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];      
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",strDialedNumber]]]; 
    }
```

Comment: iCoder, To explain: First he is checking whether the code is being run on iphone or not. Because ipad and ipod don't have call functionality. Then he is removing extra spaces (if any), in the phone number and then he is placing a call. Hope this is clear

Comment: @sathyam I can understand what the code says... Bt my doubt is about the device whether itz using any special protocols to transfer the call or else itz initiating itz own dialing func..

Answer (score 2):

If you run the code, iOS will make ***an outgoing call*** to the specified phone number. iOS uses its native **Phone** app to make the call.

Note that there should be no special characters in the phone number. It should contain only the numberic digits.

Have a look at the [Reference from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1).

Comment: Whether the device is using any special protocols or else itz initiating the itz own dialing ..

Answer (score 2):

try this:-

```
NSString *telephoneString=[self.phone stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        NSMutableString *str1=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:telephoneString];
        [str1 setString:[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""]];
        [str1 setString:[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""]];
        [str1 setString:[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""]];
        [str1 setString:[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]];
        telephoneString = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:str1];
        [str1 release];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telephoneString]];
```

Comment: Is there any possibilty to send autotext messages to the users (similar to call waiting) when the call is in hold or busy

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://9016098909891"]];
```

Comment: I think both urs and mine will act same

Comment: i got answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574291/call-safari-in-iphone-program/3574366#3574366